# How do you pass a variable to a custom string interpolator

Tags: scala, string-interpolation

In the worksheet below, I've created a custom string interpolator.

```
object WSLookup {

  implicit class LookupSC(val sc: StringContext) extends AnyVal {
    def lookup(args: Any*): String = {
      val strings = sc.parts.iterator
      val expressions = args.iterator
      var buf = new StringBuffer(strings.next)

      while (strings.hasNext) {
        buf append doLookup(expressions.next.toString)
        buf append strings.next
      }
      buf.toString()
    }

    def doLookup(s: String): String = {
      // Just change the string to uppercase to test.
      s.toUpperCase
    }
  }

  val x = "cool"
  val testString = "Not $x"
  lookup"How $x"

  // lookup testString //<--- See question 1
}
```

I have two questions regarding this:

1. How do you use the string interpolator on variables
2. How do you pass or use an additional argument to your string interpolator. Say for example my string interpolator is used to lookup variables from a file, but I want to specify the file name on the fly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. String interpolation translates to direct method call at compile time, so you can't use it on variables
2. I'm not sure that I understand you correctly, but you can try implicit parameters:

   ```
   implicit class TestInt(val sc: StringContext) extends AnyVal {
       def test(args: Any*)(implicit prefix: String): String = 
           prefix + sc.s(args:_*)
   }

   implicit val p = "> "
   val x = 1
   println(test"x = $x")
   ```

as @didier-dupont suggests you can use second parameters list without implicits:

```
implicit class TestInt(val sc: StringContext) extends AnyVal {
    def test(args: Any*)(prefix: String): String =
        prefix + sc.s(args:_*)
}
val p = "> "
val x = 1
println(test"x = $x"(p))
```

Comment: It does not need to be implicit (it may or may not be convenient depending on the use case). A second parameters list just works. Anyway the lookup method is not required to return a string, which leaves many possibilities open.

Comment: Thanks for tip about second parameters list. Yes, interpolation result may be any class, it's just a sample.